# Jquery no behavior on click

Tags: jquery

I have a div with an id called `#wrapper`. Next to it I have button. When the button is clicked, an ajax call is triggered returning a list of divs with a class called `.calendarDate`. Everything works great, `#wrapper` is populated fine.

Now I am trying to have a click event on that `.calendarDate` class, but it is not working. The strange part is that the CSS properties I apply to that class are working properly. Hope someone can acknowledge about that strange behavior. By he way, no errors in my debugger. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc

My PHP: working great

```
Here i set my variables...

while($input<$inDays){
    ++$input;
    $test=$input." days";
    if($input<0){$attribut='"avant"';}else{$attribut='"apres"';}
    echo '<div class="calendarDate" indiDate=' .$attribut. '>' .date('Y-m-d', strtotime($test)). '</div>';
}
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#wrapper').load('php/calendar2.php');
$('.calendarDate').click(function(){
        alert('Whaou!');
    });
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
        <input id="envoyer" type="submit" multiplicateur="1">
```

Comment: We need to see your code. Stick it in a pastebin.

Comment: Better: Create a http://jsfiddle.net demo and post the relevant here. Do you seriously expect anyone beeing able to help you by just telling us *I have a and b but behaviour z does not work*?

Comment: I can't make a JS Fiddle as my div is populated by an ajax call

Comment: @FelixKling This kind of questions 'after loading via AJAX my click event not working' tells everithing even without code.. But you are right although.

Comment: @dfsq: For what we know, the OP could also be binding the event handler inside the callback and the problem could be something totally different. If it is a question about code, it should include code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're binding the click event to the calendarDate class before it exists.  Try using this to bind the event handler instead...

```
$(document).on("click", ".calendarDate", function() {
    // etc
}
```

That will fire the click event handler to all elements with a class of calendarDate, regardless of whether they exist at document ready or not.

Comment: `$("document")` should be `$(document)` or why not `$(document.body)`.

Comment: @FelixKling Ooops!  Thanks :)  I use document out of habit.  In fairness, I'd recommend using the nearest container, but this is just a working example.

Comment: Hello Archer. You rock! It is working :) I do not really understand your explanations though. I will check on the jquery website about that .on(). Thanks again

Comment: Glad to help mate.  On is just an event binder, but yeah, check on the jQuery site because as you know their docs are usually excellent.

Comment: @FelixKling. or why not `$('body')... =)

Comment: The nearest consistent container is always the best way to go, whatever that may be.

Answer (score 2):

You bind your click event with `click`. Instead use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). If you are using jQuery < 1.7 you should use `.delegate()`:

```
$('#wrapper').delegate('.calendarDate', 'click', function() {
    // this should work
});
```

If you are using jQuery 1.7+ you should use `.on()`:

```
$('#wrapper').on('click', '.calendarDate', function() {
    // this should work
});
```

Comment: Hello dfsq. Your solution work's as well. I need to read about that .delegate as I do not know what that is. thanks...

Answer (score 1):

A likely cause of the issue (can't be sure without seeing the code) is that you are trying to bind the click events when the page loads, so the `.calendarDate` elements do not exist. Make sure you don't add the click events for the `.calendarDate` elements until *after* you add the `.calendarDate` elements to the page.

Comment: Thanks jim I understand better with all your explanations

Answer (score 1):

The element doesnt exist when you bind the event in document ready? You need to bind the click  event onto `.calendardate` after the ajax call is successful and you've injected the markup into the dom - or use `.live` or `.delegate` instead of `.click`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.calendarDate').bind('click', function() {
   alert('Replace the alert with your code.');
});
```

That's really all I can say without seeing your code to check for errors. If you have elements that are generated dynamically try replacing the .bind() with .live().