# Call a function after appending button

Tags: jquery

I make jQuery code add HTML elemnet button2 when event click on button1  ,
and make another to add another HTML element to DIV when click on button2
the first one runs but the second not. How to solve this problem ?

Example of problem

```
var button2='<input type="button" vale="add" id="idbutton2" >';
$('#idbutton1').click(function(){
  $('#divid1').html(button2);
});

$('#idbutton2').click(function(){
  $('#divid2').html("text");
});
```

The button2 adds to DIV and I want to run jQuery when click on button2 occurs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery no behavior on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083768/jquery-no-behavior-on-click)

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
$('#divid1').on('click', '#idbutton2', function(){
    $('#divid2').html("text");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.on` instead to delegate the event handler.

```
$(document).on('click', '#idbutton2', function(){
  $('#divid2').html("text");
});
```

Or you could bind it on button2 directly.

```
var button2= $('<input type="button" vale="add" id="idbutton2" >').click(function(){
  $('#divid2').html("text");
});

$('#idbutton1').click(function(){
    $('#divid1').html(button2.html());
});
```